# How to use Financial Function in c#, like EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel, finance

How to use Financial Function in c#,  like EXCEL

For example,   IRR,
Present Value,
Future Value,
NPV,
etc.

I have found this link, but i doesn't work for me. I added Finance.dll,  but I dont know how to do next.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions

if you have better solution help please tell me or  give sample one example from the link above.

Thank you

Comment: You need to be clearer about what isn't working. Do you have some code, or errors to help?

Comment: If you read carefully it says **The functions are provided as static methods on a Financial class in the System.Numeric namespace**

Comment: @RJLohan I don't have the code  because i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @riseres Would you please post how you solved it, preferably as an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Just do as V4Vendelta said

and use the static method; for example, in method,

Finance.xxxx (it will automatic show intellicence

Comment: Thank you for your followup. As a question and answer site having questions without answers significantly increases the noise on the site.  If the @V4Vendetta comment was the solution then they should post that as an answer.

Comment: @riseres Have added it as answer you may choose to accept the same !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read fine the page you have posted for Excel financial functions.

> How do I use the library?
>
> Just add Financial.dll to the references in
> your project. The functions are provided as static methods on a
> Financial class in the System.Numeric namespace

So if you reference it this way the static methods would be available.